# Function printing "waiting" while waits for value from another function

Tags: python, multithreading

How do I do the `receive` function to `print "waiting"` while the function `send` does not send the args?

Well, I really don't know how I can do it, I thought about `join()` method, but I tried this:

```
import threading
import random

waiting = True

def receive(a=""):
    while waiting:
        print "[receive] waiting for args"
    print "[receive] Args received: %s" % a # args received from send function

def send(args):
    global waiting
    if waiting:
        if random.randint(1,3) == 2:
            waiting = False
            print "[send] Args sent"
            receive(a=args) # send the args

fargs = ["hello, world", "foo", "bar", "foobar", 12]

t1 = threading.Thread(target=receive, args=[])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=send, args=[fargs])

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Sometimes this works, but sometimes I get in a infinite loop.

**@EDIT**

Now it works fine:

```
import threading
import random

waiting = True

def receive(a=""):
    while waiting:
        print "[receive] waiting for args"
    if a:
        print "[receive] Args received: %s" % a
def send(args):
    global waiting
    while waiting:
        if random.randint(1,3) == 2:
            waiting = False
            print "[send] Args sent"
            receive(a=args)

fargs = ["hello, world", "foo", "bar", "foobar", 12]

t1 = threading.Thread(target=receive, args=[])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=send, args=[fargs])


t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: _"sometimes I get in a infinite loop."_ Makes sense to me. When `random.randint` doesn't equal 2, then `send` never sends anything, so `receive` loops forever. What do you expect to happen? (by the way, you probably don't need to call `receive` in `send`, since an instance of `receive` is already running)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is quite old, but expanding on the self answer by OP i created a class that prints a string while a given function is running.

```
import threading
import queue
import time
import getpass

class DotsPrinter:
   def __init__(self, float_dots_frequency=1, 
                string_to_print_while_waiting="."):
    self.float_dots_frequency = float_dots_frequency
    self.string_to_print_while_waiting = string_to_print_while_waiting
    self.bool_waiting = True
    self.output_queue = queue.Queue()

    def print_dots(self):
        if self.bool_waiting:
            print("Waiting ", end="", flush=True)
        while self.bool_waiting:
            print(self.string_to_print_while_waiting, end="", 
                  flush=True)
            time.sleep(self.float_dots_frequency)

    def function_wrapper(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.output_queue.put(function(*args, **kwargs))
        self.bool_waiting = False

    def print_dots_while_executing(self, function, *args, **kwargs):

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.print_dots)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.function_wrapper, args=
                              [function, *args], kwargs={**kwargs})
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        return self.output_queue.get()
```

the usage is quite simple:

```
def count_till_timeout(timeout):
    start_time = time.time()
    n = 0
    while time.time() - start_time < timeout:
        n += 1
    return n

n = DotsPrinter().print_dots_while_executing(count_till_timeout, 5)
print(n)
```

I didn't test it exstensively so it might have some bugs, and i am not an expert with threading, therefore I don't know if a thing like this should be done, but I hope it helps someone. I'm using it to print dots while pandas downloads data from a sql DB.